# Recurring Dates from SQL Database into SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, default-value, recurring-events

I'm creating an employee birthday calendar, where the dates are being pulled from a separate database through SQL. Since these are birthdays, each event needs to be recurring. I'm not sure if there is a way for the SQL data to set the recurrence items in the SharePoint list, or if I need recurrence to either default to 1 year, or set up a workflow to automatically update the recurrence after the event is created.
On another note, I need All Day Event to default to yes, but I figure that answer will become clear with the answer to recurrence.

For reference, I'm using SharePoint 2013 Foundation and SPD 2013. I do not have jquery set up at all, and I wouldn't even know where to start with it.

Comment: are you going to import from sql to SP list or just creating new items in calender with new items. the later will be pretty much straight forward where you can choose the recurrent events and all day events.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response, I was waiting for a meeting with our database developer. I will be created an external list type in SharePoint linked to a SQL database. This list will be used to populate a SharePoint calendar. I want the calendar list and the SQL table to always match, but I also need to set the recurrence on the calendar list item.